# R - filter a list based on names which start with a numerical value

Tags: r

I have the following list in R:

```
x <- list("a"="m","a2"="test","001"="test2","002"="test3")

$a
[1] "m"

$a2
[1] "test"

$`001`
[1] "test2"

$`002`
[1] "test3"
```

I want to filter this list so that it returns only the items which begin with a number, i.e. it would return:

```
x$001 and x$002
```

Comment: In what sense do those items "begin with a number"?  You mean their names (`001` and `002` are numbers?)

Comment: Given the example names `a2` and `001`, I think `a2` begins with a letter, `001` begins with a number.

Comment: @Gregor yes - that's what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter hasn't picked it up yet, so I'll post my comment as an answer. We can use the regex pattern `"^[0-9]"` to find strings that start with a number. Applying that to the names of your list:

```
x[grepl("^[0-9]", names(x))]
# $`001`
# [1] "test2"
# 
# $`002`
# [1] "test3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you mean here, but two possibilities that take advantage of the fact that you can filter a list by supplying a vector within single brackets

If what you want is elements of the list that have numbers in them:

```
x[sapply(x, function(i){grepl("[0-9]", i)})]
```

If what you want is elements of the list that have a name that can be interpreted as a number:

```
x[!is.na(as.numeric(names(x)))]
```

Comment: OP says "begin with a number", a better regex might be `"^[0-9]"`. I think what OP wants is `x[grepl("^[0-9]", names(x))]`